# Can anyone recommend an existing java file repository

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, grails, ms-word

that will allow my users to edit word documents locally in Word and have them saved back to the server when finished.

The project will be Grails based and I'm looking at things like WebDav but I would need security features that won't allow one user to access another users documents.

And unfortunately the test I ran opening a word document via a WebDav URL first downloaded the file rather than opening directly. So when saved, for example it just saved to c:\download\mydoc.doc.

So I'm looking for alternative ideas if anyone has any thoughts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this list http://java-source.net/open-source/content-managment-systems

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/).

---

### Update

Enabled access protocols are listed in [documentation](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Repository_Architecture#Which_Protocol_Shall_I_Use_Today.3F) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfresco_(software)#Features).

- CIFS/SMB
- FTP
- WebDAV
- CMIS

Comment: Do these products allow for Word Documents to be edited and resent to the server upon save?

Comment: Repository access via CIFS/SMB, FTP, WebDAV and CMIS.